# Map external folder to kubernetes pod using volume and env

Tags: kubernetes

I will define volume in a docker-compose file like this, how can I define the same config directory in the Kubernetes YAML file

```
volumes:
- /home/builduser/jenkins/workspace/deploy/config:/app/sources/config
environment:
- CONF_DIR=/app/sources/config
```

Answer (score 0):

In K8, it is slightly different and more expressive. You can define by first define your config and then mount it into the K8 resources(Pod, Deployment, RC)

**1:** Create config by command line by using `--from-file=<file-path>`

```
kubectl create configmap special-config --from-file="/app/sources/config" # please verify once created
```

**2:** Populate a Volume with data stored in a ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "date" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        # Provide mount path 
        mountPath: /home/builduser/jenkins/workspace/deploy/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: here we dont want to provide environment variable? thanks in advance

Comment: Good question- consider a scenario if you have env variable in your app and down the line, if you want to update env var, the only option is to change in the code ( + restart). However, with `configMap` (and `secret`) which is another best practice to expose the env data. You can try by use `env` onto pod by `kubectl exec <pod-name> -- env`.

Comment: Your next question is off the topic and not relevant to this Meanwhile you can follow the k8 link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap. And Please accept the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

What you do here, are actually two different things:

> ```
> volumes:
> - /home/builduser/jenkins/workspace/deploy/config:/app/sources/config
> environment:
> - CONF_DIR=/app/sources/config
> ```

1. you map some directory in your container to your local filesystem
2. you define environment variable in your container

If your goal is to map some directory available within your `Pod`, to your `Node`'s filesystem, this can be done in kubernetes in a few different ways e.g. with [hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), already mentioned by [Danylo Patsora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15756763/danylo-patsora) in his answer. You can also take a look at [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volumes.

Second thing can be done quite easily, by simply defining an environment variable which should be available in your `Pod`, which is described in [this fragment of the official kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container).

Your final creation might look something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    env:
    - name: CONF_DIR
      value: "/app/sources/config"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /app/sources/config # directory location within container
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /home/builduser/jenkins/workspace/deploy/config
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

Answer (score -1):

I see 2 possible ways:

1. You define all the config files in K8s configmaps, mount them to same folder and pass an ENV with the path to folder. To read more about Configmap visit  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/
2. If you need to access K8s Node file system you can try Hostpath - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath.

**I would recommend to use the first one**, because it will be easier to manage configmaps, than manage K8s node file system